# Water heater will not stay lit

Tags: water

I have a Rheem hot water tank. When I hold down on the pilot light button & push the igniter,  the pilot light lights but when I let up on it so I can turn on the burner .. it goes out. It's driving me nuts! I already replaced the thermocouple, purged the tank, cleaned all the contacts inside. The lines aren't clogged with any debris.. That glass/oil safety shut off seems to be fine.  I can't seem to figure out the problem. There are no lights on the tank like other tanks have that may give ma a hint as to the problem. I don't know what else to do?

Comment: How long do you hold down the button? It can take up to a minute to heat up the thermocouple.

Comment: is the thermocouple inside the pilot light flame?

Comment: The valve itself could also fail, call Rheem.

Comment: At least a minute

Comment: Yes it is inside the flame.

Comment: Every video I googled said that if it's the control valve .. the pilot light won't even light at all! I am clueless! I will try to call Rheem. Thank you

Comment: Was it the correct thermocouple or a generic? You could have gotten a defective thermocouple.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could've gotten a defective one. I'm not exactly sure what kind it is. I believe generic! Its not exactly the same as was on there! The end that's in the pilot light is larger than the one that was on there

Comment: Could someone please help me troubleshoot this nightmare of mine??? I am still stumped on what could be causing my water heater problems?  Does anyone have any clues?  It's probably something simple  .. I hope! I just can't figure it out!